# How to custom ticks and bars in Python?

Tags: python, time-series, bar-chart, xticks

I want to see the frequency of occurrence of some event,  when my event happened and when didn’t.

How can I custom the plot in a way that have years on the x-axis from 1970 to 2020 in order (1years interval), and have the bars where there are data and empty ticks where there are no data.

```
list1=[2019, 2016, 2014, 2014, 2011, 2008, 2005, 2004, 2003, 1994, 1992, 1989, 1988, 1984, 1983, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1977, 1975, 1973, 1970]
a=pd.Series(data=list1);a

A=a.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(figsize=(15, 3), color='darkblue')

plt.title(' A Occurrence ')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1=[2019, 2016, 2014, 2014, 2011, 2008, 2005, 2004, 2003, 1994, 1992, 1989, 1988, 1984, 1983, 1981, 1980, 1979, 1977, 1975, 1973, 1970]
a = pd.Series(list1)
A = a.value_counts().to_frame()
A.columns = ['cnt']
idx = np.arange(min(list1), max(list1)+1)
A = A.reindex(index=idx.tolist(), fill_value=0)
A.sort_index(axis=0,inplace=True)
A.plot.bar(figsize=(15, 3), color='darkblue')

plt.title(' A Occurrence ')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I need to have all the years from 1970 to 2020 on my horizontal axis. For example between 1970 and 1973, I need two more ticks, empty, without bars. In this case, I can understand at a glance that 1970 and 1973 have data but 1971 and 1972 nothing.

Comment: Did you need all the years to your question? Updated codes and graphs.